# Finding random youtube videos of a specific language with subtitles

Tags: youtube, web-crawler, google-crawlers

i would like to crawl Youtube for videos of a specific language that contains subtitles/closed-captions(CC).

For example,

1. I want to crawl for 200 random English videos with English subtitles/(CC).
2. I want to crawl for 300 random Chinese videos with Chinese subtitles/(CC).
3. I want to crawl for 550 random Malay videos with Malay subtitles/(CC).

There's an [api](https://github.com/jdepoix/youtube-transcript-api) here that helps to extract transcripts, but the main bottleneck right now is that i have to go youtube to search for these videos and watch one by one to find out if they are indeed in the correct language, and if they really contain subtitles/CC.

Answer (score 1):

An option is:

- Use [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) - [`search`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=en) request for search videos that contains subtitles; for that, use `videoCaption` parameter with value: `closedCaption`.

  - You might need use another parameters for reduce the search terms to specific topics or get certain desired results; for example, for the `q` parameter, use a search term that retrieves the desired results; also all parameters like: `videoDuration`, `type` = video, `relevanceLanguage`.
- Once you got such results, copy/paste the `videoId` you got from the results of the request and use your web-crawler for get more videos and the related ones.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this, and as per the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) for `videoCaption` to work, you need to also set the `type` parameter's value to video:

> If you specify a value for this parameter, you must also set the type
> parameter's value to video.